# RelatedTo relation - checking matrix block status is enabled

Tags: craft3, relations, relatedto

I need to search for all commerce variants related to a custom element "Account".

The account element is related to a variant through a matrix field with handle
`varientaccountmapping`, block handle `mapping` field handle `account`

```
{% set allowedVarients = craft.variants().relatedTo({
    targetElement: accountElement,
    field: 'varientaccountmapping.account'
}).all() %}
```

works, however it returns results whether the matrix block is enabled or disabled - ignoring the status.

How can I get this to return only results where the matrix block it is related to is **enabled**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the [same problem](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/additional-criteria-to-filter-status-of-field-passed-into-relatedto) in Craft v3.4.10 and have been informed that this is a [bug](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5849), which has now been fixed and will be shipped in v3.4.12.