# Additional criteria to filter status of field passed into RelatedTo

Tags: craft3, assets, matrix, relatedto

I'm trying to save all the images related to an `entry` in a variable. I need the images that are added through a *matrix field* in the entry. I'm using the following code, but am then also getting images associated with *disabled* *matrix blocks*. I only need images from *matrix blocks* that are *enabled*.

FYI - `body` and `builder` are *matrix fields* and `asset` is the corresponding *block handle*.

```
{% set imageAssets = craft.assets().relatedTo([
  'or', 
  { sourceElement: entry, field: 'body.asset' },
  { sourceElement: entry, field: 'builder.asset' },
]).all() %}
```

Is there a way I can add conditions onto the fields that I am passing into the `relatedTo` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a Craft bug. I’ve posted an issue for it at https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5849, and fixed it for the next release (3.4.12).